# Appending a vector using case_when R

Tags: r

I am trying to add a vector of arguments to a nested dataframe, later to be used as addons to the regression formula I will be running with this data. However, I am not able to.. any thoughts?

```
library(tidyverse)

flights <- nycflights13::flights
flights<- sample_n(flights, 1000)
nested <- flights %>% group_by(origin, dest) %>% 
  nest() ## groups all the data by the sub series

nested %>% mutate (formula = "airtime ~ distance + carrier")
nested<-nested %>% mutate (add_in = case_when(
  
  origin =="EWR" & dest =="CVG"  ~  list("year", "hour"),
  origin =="EWR" & dest =="LAX"  ~  list("year", "dep_delay")
))
```

This may have 17-20 different models , with the same basic formula (only addons). is there a cleaner way to do this for 20 models?

Comment: You are trying to add a vector of values which will cause the length to differ

Comment: Yes akrun is right.  Either do it in list col or in character

Comment: I need to concat it later in the beginning of another vector..

Comment: In your new line with `list`, it should be  `list` with one element i.e. `list(c("year", "hour"))` as in my post so as to match the length

Comment: Thanks. The point is to make the formula for the first line for example to be : airtime ~ year + hour + distance + carrier

Comment: Does the `distance` and `carrier` remains the same in the formula for both cases

Comment: Yes. its just different add ons

Comment: My doubt is that `airtime ~ distance + carrier + year + hour` for the first case and `airtime ~ distance + carrier + year + dep_delay` for the second case?

Comment: I added an update.  Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I have multiple datasets , I think how to add two as params and not in text..

Comment: @Stat.Enthus Not clear about your case.  The solution is based on your input example showed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could either have a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
nested %>% 
 mutate(add_in =  case_when(
  origin =="EWR" & dest =="CVG"  ~ list(c("sno", "sno2","sno3")),
 origin =="EWR" & dest =="LAX"  ~  list(c("sno", "sno2","sno3"))))
```

or `paste` them together (`toString` -> `paste(., collapse=", ")`) as a single string

```
nested %>% 
  mutate(add_in =  case_when(
   origin =="EWR" & dest =="CVG"  ~ toString(c("sno", "sno2","sno3")),
   origin =="EWR" & dest =="LAX"  ~  toString(c("sno", "sno2","sno3"))))
```

#### Update

If we need to create a `formula` object, can do this with `paste` or `reformulate`

```
out <- nested %>%
   mutate(add_in = case_when(
  origin =="EWR" & dest =="CVG"  ~  
     list(reformulate(c("distance", "carrier", "year", "hour"), "airtime")), 
     origin =="EWR" & dest =="LAX" 
     ~ list(reformulate(c("distance", "carrier", "year", 
       "dep_delay"), "airtime"))))
```

Comment: And how to do it in lists?

Comment: @AnilGoyal You can just replace the `toString` with `list`

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my code at the question to make it more clear..

Comment: @Stat.Enthus Are you updating this `nested %>% mutate (formula = "airtime ~ distance + carrier")` to your original dataset